# Listview How to go to next/new row?

Tags: flutter, listview

I have been using flutter for past few months and now I have stuck in a problem where i have to design a ui to show the button to user as the image given below.

I want to go to new row inside a listview, anyone know how to make it ?

[image]

```
Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            height: 35,
            child: ListView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              children: [
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () async {
                        setState(() {
                          category2 = 1;
                        });
                        print("Selection Setting and Testing");
                      },
                      child: Card(
                          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 27, 175, 224),
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                            child: Column(
                              children: [
                                Text(
                                  "Selection Setting and Testing",
                                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          )),
                    ),
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () async {
                        setState(() {
                          category2 = 2;
                        });
                        print("Selection Capacity");
                      },
                      child: Card(
                          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 27, 175, 224),
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                            child: Column(
                              children: [
                                Text(
                                  "Selection Capacity",
                                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          )),
                    ),
```

Comment: Please try to add your code snippet

Comment: I have added my answer below please try this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**`Wrap`**](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Wrap-class.html) widget instead of Listview hope its help to you.

```
Wrap(
  // spacing: 8.0, // gap between adjacent chips
  //  runSpacing: 4.0, // gap between lines
  direction: Axis.horizontal,
  children: [
    GestureDetector(
      onTap: () async {
        print("Selection Setting and Testing");
      },
      child: Card(
        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 27, 175, 224),
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Text(
                "Selection Setting and Testing",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        print("Selection Capacity1");
      },
      child: Card(
        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 27, 175, 224),
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Text(
                "Selection Capacity",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        print("Selection Capacity2");
      },
      child: Card(
        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 27, 175, 224),
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Text(
                "Selection Capacity",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        print("Selection Capacity3");
      },
      child: Card(
        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 27, 175, 224),
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Text(
                "Selection Capacity",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        print("Selection Capacity4");
      },
      child: Card(
        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 27, 175, 224),
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Text(
                "Selection Capacity",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

Result-> [image]

Comment: the second row and third row GestureDetector not working  do u know y ?

Comment: @newcomer I have update my answer please check I remove the `Container` widget and your problem is resolve now

Comment: it works now with Container Remove. Thanks. Problem resolve. @Ravindra S.Patil

Comment: @newcomer Most Welcome Enjoy your ride with flutter